# spark-submit to remote Spark

Tags: .net, windows, apache-spark, kubernetes, spark-submit

Currently I've deployed Spark to `minikube` in my local machine. Pod and its containers are up and running, and I've already checked that port `7077` is listening from the host machine (local machine).

Now I want to `spark-submit` from the host machine. Thus, I've downloaded Spark's binaries and I've moved them to `c:\bin\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2`, and I've added `c:\bin\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\bin` to the `PATH`.

When I run `spark-submit`as follows...

```
spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner --master spark.local:7077 microsoft-spark-3-2_2.12-2.1.1.jar dotnet C:\projects\xxx\xxx-dotnet-solution\xx-services/infrastructure/etl-service/Spark/bin/Debug/netcoreapp3.1/xxx.xx.Services.Infraestructure.ETLService.Spark.dll
```

...I get the following error `org.apache.spark.SparkException: Could not parse Master URL: 'spark.local'`.

I'm not sure if I'm mistaken, and maybe the issue is I can't `spark-submit` from my local machine to the remote Spark. Is this ever possible?

Comment: How are the `.net` and `windows` tags related to the question? The error says it doesn't like the URL parameter. According to the [master URL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) that parameter accepts either some keywords like `local`, `yarn` or specific URL protocols, `spark://`, `mesos://`, `k8s://`. It can't handle machine or domain names

Comment: It's related in terms of I'm implementing the app using [.NET for Spark](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/apps/data/spark) on Windows.

Comment: It uses the keyword `local`, not a host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [master URL docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html#master-urls) that parameter accepts either some keywords like `local`, `yarn` or specific URL protocols, `spark://`, `mesos://`, `k8s://`. It can't handle machine or domain names.

In the [.NET for Apache Spark tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/spark/tutorials/get-started?tabs=windows) the command uses the `local` keyword, not a host name :

```
spark-submit ^
--class org.apache.spark.deploy.dotnet.DotnetRunner ^
--master local ^
microsoft-spark-3-0_2.12-<version>.jar ^
dotnet MySparkApp.dll <path-of-input.txt>
```

From the docs :

> The master URL passed to Spark can be in one of the following formats:
>
> | Master URL | Meaning |
> | --- | --- |
> | local | Run Spark locally with one worker thread (i.e. no parallelism at all). |
> | local[K] | Run Spark locally with K worker threads (ideally, set this to the number of cores on your machine). |
> | local[K,F] | Run Spark locally with K worker threads and F maxFailures (see spark.task.maxFailures for an explanation of this variable). |
> | local[*] | Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine. |
> | local[*,F] | Run Spark locally with as many worker threads as logical cores on your machine and F maxFailures. |
> | local-cluster[N,C,M] | Local-cluster mode is only for unit tests. It emulates a distributed cluster in a single JVM with N number of workers, C cores per worker and M MiB of memory per worker. |
> | spark://HOST:PORT | Connect to the given Spark standalone cluster master. The port must be whichever one your master is configured to use, which is 7077 by default. |
> | spark://HOST1:PORT1,HOST2:PORT2 | Connect to the given Spark standalone cluster with standby masters with Zookeeper. The list must have all the master hosts in the high availability cluster set up with Zookeeper. The port must be whichever each master is configured to use, which is 7077 by default. |
> | mesos://HOST:PORT | Connect to the given Mesos cluster. The port must be whichever one your is configured to use, which is 5050 by default. Or, for a Mesos cluster using ZooKeeper, use mesos://zk://.... To submit with --deploy-mode cluster, the HOST:PORT should be configured to connect to the MesosClusterDispatcher. |
> | yarn | Connect to a YARN cluster in client or cluster mode depending on the value of --deploy-mode. The cluster location will be found based on the HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR variable. |
> | k8s://HOST:PORT | Connect to a Kubernetes cluster in client or cluster mode depending on the value of --deploy-mode. The HOST and PORT refer to the Kubernetes API Server. It connects using TLS by default. In order to force it to use an unsecured connection, you can use k8s://http://HOST:PORT. |

Comment: Hey, thanks. It seems that now we're in the right track. Once I've provided `spark://` url, now I'm getting this error `22/10/19 12:00:20 INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark.local/127.0.0.1:7077 after 34 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
22/10/19 12:00:20 ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 7610044918020799059 to spark.local/127.0.0.1:7077: java.io.IOException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine`.

Comment: `127.0.0.1` is the local machine. Why use the machine name instead of `local`? Have you tried with `--master local` ? If Spark runs on Kubernetes you need to use `k8s://`. You probably also need to configure ingress

Comment: Yeah, check my question. Actually, Spark is running in minikube. Thus, the submitted app isn't going to run in a `local` Spark.

Comment: I mean that I'm submitting an app from my local machine to k8s (also in my machine, but Spark is running in k8s, it's not in the host machine).

Comment: If Spark runs on Kubernetes you need to use `k8s://`. You probably also need to configure ingress

Comment: Actually I don't want to put my effort on configuring Spark on Kubernetes. It's just for development purposes. In production environment, for now Spark won't be deployed to Kubernetes. I need to submit the app to this Spark running as a simple container in some pod (https://hub.docker.com/r/3rdman/dotnet-spark).

Comment: It should work, shouldn't it?

Comment: In that case why not start with just a Docker image? Kubernetes requires juggling a lot of balls to connect to a pod from the host. WSL2 is a full Linux environment so you can run any Linux docker container

Comment: I see, I see. But there's already an ingress/service and it's correctly exposed to the local machine.

Comment: Actually, now `spark-submit` connects to Spark. But it seems that there's another issue once it gets connected...

Comment: `It should work, shouldn't it?` Check [this Spark on Minikube tutorial](https://testdriven.io/blog/deploying-spark-on-kubernetes/). There are 4 different manifest files that need to be just right, and the final one is the `Ingress` manifest that allows clients outside the host to connect to Spark.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Actually, it's what I've already done (I did it without a tutorial, but it's almost the same as your link). Spark is already exposed this way.

Comment: Check that now output says `INFO TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to spark.local/127.0.0.1:7077 after 22 ms`. Then, it throws the exception `ERROR TransportClient: Failed to send RPC RPC 4688081008390631055 to spark.local/127.0.0.1:7077`.

Comment: Haha, I'm stupid. I've gave `local` and it worked flawlessly!